# ISP blocks PPTP. Forward PPTP traffic using external node?

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, pptp

Given:

- Remote VPN PPTP server on work that i need to connect, and which, obviously i cannot configure.
- Me, at home with ISP which block GRE traffic.
- external linux VDS (ubuntu server) on which i can run any software and which have access to PPTP vpn (because GRE there is not blocked)

Is there any setup to connect to work VPN PPTP throught external VDS?

I am at linux mint 17.3 and technically advanced user, but have no clue in networks.

Comment: You did check to make sure it's not your own router blocking PPTP?  I once fought with this for an entire day before being asked if I had enabled PPTP passthrough on my router.

Comment: It's internet proven that my ISP block GRE, many users were whining about it on internet. Many of them is also technically advanced users (network experts and so on).

Comment: Can't you connect your VDS to your work and then connect to  your VDS from your computer - basically bridging the devices through your VDS?